# Create a link listing in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, divi

So I've got a little problem with wordpress and divi and I would like to know if any of you would be able to help me. So here is the deal. I have a website where I want to create a custom post type. In the custom post type, there will be only a few details like the title, date and a link.
And what I want is when I display the 5 last custom post type as list on the front end with divi, I would like the read more button to go straight to the link inserted in the custom post type (not the permalink of the CPT). I can't seem to find a way to do this if anyone have the answer. In short, I would like to display a link listing on my wordpress website.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: What did you try? What does the link look like? Is it in the post_content? Or an ACF? Do you want to use javascript for this?

Comment: Actually, non-developper people will add the link themselves afterwards so I want it the easiest way for them. The final look I'm wanting to achieve is like that :
[Desired Front end][1]
I am using ACF and this it what the CPT content looks like : 
[CPT content][2]
And it's the link URL shown there that I want to be directly in the "lire plus" button on the previous screenshot. I am willing to do a jquery or javascript workaround on the front end if the back end stays easy to modify.
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZzyi.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCwiu.png

Comment: If you create a child theme, you can insert the link yourself. Just create the template for the page in your child theme, read the ACF link and insert `<a href="<?php echo $the_link; ?>" >READ MORE</a>`

Comment: It's not really clear what your premises are. The javascript-way is also possible, but you will need a way to get the url somehow on the page before you can use it. Which would involve using php on the server-side.

Comment: Do you want to use a child theme? Do you already have one? Are you comfortable coding php? What's your background?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I am less or more comfortable with php but I wouldn't say that I am an expert nor a senior. There is no child theme yet so I'm going to try that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer and I let it here if anyone has the same struggle (I doubt it since it was fairly easy finaly but still lol). So what I did is that I created a custom post type with ACF (you can do it manually, still works). I then added a link custom field where I added the link.

Instead of creating a child theme, I installed WP Code Snippet which allowed me to create a code snippet and display it wherever I want using a short code.

In the snippet I just called `get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'custom_link_field_slug', true);` to display the link and assign it wherever I want. So thanks for guiding me @Klaassiek